# IDA PRO Structures Defining negative offset -4 -8 offset repair asm Hex-Rays

Tags: ida, struct

How do I fix structures in IDA PRO so they show up properly in Hex-Rays plugin (C decompiler).

Similar question to: (But the solution doesn't work for me)
 [Struct with negative offset in IDA possible](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/struct-with-negative-offset-in-ida-possible)

Pretty much what happened is I compiled a very good program and it works right, after that I did many changes to it and now it works worse then the older version, I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong (since I lost the source code now) to revert back to the old version. (I also added below the original piece of the code written in C++, which didn't change between both versions).

Structure's addresses somehow optimized in IDA PRO
Such as that

```
*(_BYTE *)(shipsStruct + 279) = 1; //Ships[i].used = true;
```

should really be `[10x4]=40+255= 295`

```
*(_BYTE *)(shipsStruct + 295) = 1;  //Ships[i].used = true;
```

You can tell the structure size right here (`shipsStruct += 296;`)

I'm guessing somehow the un-used structure members are stripped out (but why is the structure size valid?).
Seems the assembly somehow is offset wrongly (how do I add the proper offset deltas to the struct to fix this)?

When I try this tip http://www.hexblog.com/?p=63 
My whole IDA PRO freezes up when I select the line `mov edi, offset dword_10004C38` and press T (IDA PRO 6.1)

[image: structoffset]

Seems I made my struct incorrectly?

Here is how the code decompiled code looks like (without applying structure)

```
  if ( playerListBaseAddress && !IsBadReadPtr(playerListBaseAddress, 4u) )
  {
    shipsStruct = (int)dword_10004C38;
    while ( 1 )
    {
      playerPointer = (struct_v3 *)*((_DWORD *)playerListBaseAddress + maxPlayers);
      if ( !playerPointer )
        break;
      if ( IsBadReadPtr(playerPointer, 4u) )
        break;
      *(_DWORD *)(shipsStruct - 4) = playerPointer->ssXCoord;
      *(_DWORD *)shipsStruct = playerPointer->ssYCoord;
      *(_DWORD *)(shipsStruct + 4) = playerPointer->ssXSpeed;
      *(_DWORD *)(shipsStruct + 8) = playerPointer->ssYSpeed;
      *(_DWORD *)(shipsStruct - 8) = playerPointer->ssFreq;
      *(_DWORD *)(shipsStruct + 20) = playerPointer->ssShipNum;
      if ( playerPointer->ssPlayerName )
        strcpy_s((char *)(shipsStruct + 24), 0xFFu, &playerPointer->ssPlayerName);
      *(_BYTE *)(shipsStruct + 279) = 1;
      if ( v37 == playerPointer )
        break;
      shipsStruct += 296;
      ++maxPlayers;
      v37 = playerPointer;
      if ( shipsStruct >= (signed int)&unk_10017310 )
        goto finish;
    }
    v34 = maxPlayers;
    if ( maxPlayers < 255 )
    {
      v4 = (int)((char *)&unk_10004D4F + 296 * maxPlayers);
      do
      {
        *(_BYTE *)v4 = 0;
        v4 += 296;
      }
      while ( v4 < (signed int)&unk_10017427 );
    }
```

Here is the orginal code (not decompiled written in C++)

```
double currentTimer = GetTimer();
double timeElapsed = currentTimer - lastTimer;

int maxPlayers = 0;
DWORD lastPlayerPtr = 0;
if (playerListBaseAddress != NULL && !IsBadReadPtr((void *) playerListBaseAddress, sizeof(ULONG_PTR))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) { //populate player ship list.
    DWORD playerPtr = *(DWORD *) (playerListBaseAddress + (i * 4));

    if (playerPtr != NULL && !IsBadReadPtr((void *) playerPtr, sizeof(ULONG_PTR))) {
        Ships[i].XCoordinate = *(DWORD *) (playerPtr + 0x4);
        Ships[i].YCoordinate = *(DWORD *) (playerPtr + 0x8);
        Ships[i].XSpeed = *(signed long *) (playerPtr + 0x10);
        Ships[i].YSpeed = *(signed long *) (playerPtr + 0x14);
        Ships[i].Freq = *(DWORD *) (playerPtr + 0x58);
        Ships[i].ShipNum = *(BYTE *) (playerPtr + 0x5C)
        //memcpy(&(Ships[i].Name), (void*)((DWORD)playerPtr+0x6D), 19);
        if (!*(BYTE *) (playerPtr + 0x6D) == NULL)
        strcpy_s(Ships[i].Name, (char *) ((DWORD) playerPtr + 0x6D));
        Ships[i].used = true;

        if (lastPlayerPtr == playerPtr)
        goto finishList;
        lastPlayerPtr = playerPtr;
    } else {
      finishList:
        maxPlayers = i;
        for (int j = i; j < 255; j++)
        Ships[j].used = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is before and after (applying my custom struct)
I did the custom struct by doing a bunch of Arrays (* key), then setting proper sizes. (Guessing this isn't the proper way to make a structure in IDA PRO?)
[image: struct]

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

ASM:
[image: asm]

Edit Function
[image: edit function]

Double clicked local variable
[image: dbl click local variables]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From above...

**Decompiled:**

```
*(_DWORD *)(shipsStruct - 4) = playerPointer->ssXCoord;
*(_DWORD *)shipsStruct = playerPointer->ssYCoord;
...
```

**Original:**

```
Ships[i].XCoordinate = *(DWORD *) (playerPtr + 0x4);
Ships[i].YCoordinate = *(DWORD *) (playerPtr + 0x8);
...
```

Based on these snippets, it looks like the structure in your stack variables is 8 bytes off. Can you share with us the stack variable list for that function? (Double-click on one of the local variables in the decompilation to open the stack view.)

Comment: Talking about this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/2rANk.png here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9vKkW.png

Comment: Should I risk deleting those `db ? ;undefined` above? and how did IDA analysis mess on this. Seems 12 bytes off (All functions decompile without errors btw)

Comment: Okay I changed from `0x68` to `0x5C` now all undefined are gone begins from `var_5C` still generates same C code and everything seems the same, except for when clicking the stack variables no more undefined variables there.

Comment: Is `shipsStruct` a local variable or a global variable?

Comment: Well `shipsStruct` is declared locally from `(int)dword_10004C38` which seems to be a global location in memory that location in memory I guess somehow should represent the offsetted structure. `shipsStruct` is the name I gave it it's really suppose to be casted to `ShipStruct`. Becomes like this when I convert it to struct* `shipsStruct = (ShipStruct *)dword_10004C38;`

Comment: Even if it's just a local pointer to a global structure, it's odd that it's not in the stack variable listing for the function. Are you sure you posted the screenshot for the right function's stack listing?

Comment: Yes I did it's not in the Local Stack Variables. It seems to get generated during decompilng in Hex-Rays. it's register `edi`  `ShipStruct *shipsStruct; // edi@3` after converting to struct and before it looks like this `int shipsStruct; // edi@3`, It generates about 48 local variables even those the stack shows only 13.

Comment: Re opened the file and now it generates this without any editing anything. `v1 = (signed int)dword_10004C38;`   `signed int v1; // edi@3` (still not in the local stack variable listing)

Answer (score 5):

This feature is supported since Hex-Rays 1.6:

http://www.hexblog.com/?p=544

(see section 3. CONTAINING_RECORD macro)